# Do you need a power switch in order to conserve power in your circuit when the circuit is not running?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a circuit that will be battery powered so I want to conserve power. It is a BLDC motor circuit and i'm wondering if I need to have a power switch to completely disconnect the battery from the circuit when I am not using it in order to preserve power, or if I can just leave the battery hooked up when it's not running and the battery level will not be depleted?

Here is my circuit:
[image]

Comment: Measure the battery current when not running. If the current is not zero then you need a switch.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. But I will definitely do that @RussellH